# Install will not proceed

Tags: installation, dual-boot

OK, so I am very much new to Linux, and I have been trying for a few days to install Ubuntu alongside WindowsXP.

I have tried both bootable USB and a Live System disc. Both start and run as live systems, but when I click my language and then click continue to install, the cursor just sits and spins. I know that OS installs can sometimes take a while, but 6+ hours is a little ridiculous.

So far, here's what I have done:

- I have already partitioned the hard drive with 70GB of space while in Windows.
- I have tried installing while connected to the internet and without
  it. Nothing seems to work.
- I have also tried Ubuntu 13.10, 13.04, and 12.04.3 LTS.
- And, just for the fun of it, I even tried Zorin OS 7.1 just to see if
  it might work.

Same results with the never ending spinning cursor... I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You said that you made a 70GB partition in windows. Did you format it to ext4 or ext3 before continuing to install ubuntu. That could be the problem. Partitions made from windows get formatted into FAT or NFTS. Windows doesn't give you an option for formatting them into linux filesystems.

Don't worry if that's the problem then it's solvable. Read below.

**Warning:** If you are not careful when following below steps then they can harm your data in hard drive. So proceed with a little caution. I suggest you backup your important files.

When you try to install Ubuntu through a Live CD or a USB simply choose all the specifications normally and when you come across a option
where it asks for installation type, choose something else and click continue and then in the partition table it gives you, select the partition you want to use for Ubuntu installation and format it to ext4 or ext3(whichever you find preferably) and partition type as "Primary" by using the options given there. Click image link given below to see and get base idea.

[image]

And then don't forget to select the Mount point as `root ( / )` for installation and press Ok. If you want to make ubuntu the default bootloader then select `/dev/sda` in the "Device for bootloader" or select your preferred option. Check everything was done correct. And then finally click "Install Now".

I hope this is useful :)

Comment: Well, I appreciate the info! I will definitely refer back to this. My problem, though, is that I can't even get to the point in the installation where I choose partitions or anything other than my preferred language. The live system doesn't recognize that there is any hard drive or any other media drives attached to the system. Gparted doesn't recognize my hard drive either. I went back and deleted the partition I created, so now it is just unallocated space.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be useful but i'll add anyway. Check your ram size and the bit version  of ubuntu you downloaded. If your ram is less than 4GB and you are trying to install a 64 bit then that could be the problem. It happened to me once. Download a 32 bit version of ubuntu and try.